# Angular FormArray - Property controls does not exist on type AbstractControl

Tags: angular

I want to build Form Array in Angular7

controls get underlined in red. And I have this error before I even serve the app:

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

components

```
addSubmenugroup(j) {
    console.log(j);
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.get('submenus').controls[j].get('submenugroups');
   // console.log(control);
    control.push(this.initSubmenugroup());  
  }


  removeSubmenugroup(j){
     const control = <FormArray>this.form.get('submenus').controls[j].get('submenugroups');
     control.removeAt(j);
  }
```

When I click on submit button, it should generate form array.

Comment: try this `this.form.value.submenus[j].submenugroups`

Comment: `this.form.get('submenus')` will return you a Abstract Control! Which don't have any `controls` property

Comment: Provide a FormGroup Code and Proper explanation!

Comment: [This](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) will help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `get` method of `FormGroup` returns a value of `AbstractControl` that's why the static type checker gives you an error. `AbstractControl` itself doesn't have a `controls` property.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl more info here.

What you can do is

```
const formArray = this.form.get('submenus') as FormArray;
const secondArray = formArray.get('submenugroups`) as FormArray;
const control = secondArray.controls[...] as FormControl;

// Continue with your logic.
```

Comment: What do I put inside [...]

Comment: Because it is an array, an index of the element you want to get. If you use a FormGroup, you will need to set a `key`. e.g. `formGroup.get('someKey')`

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can use safe navigation operator `?`, in the html file.

Change:

```
yourForm.get('myField').controls
```

to:

```
myForm.get('myField')?.controls
```